# PHP naming conventions about abstract classes and interfaces

Tags: php, naming-conventions

Should an abstract class always be prefixed with `Abstract` and suffixed with `Interface` (when it's an interface)? Is there any standard naming convention, similar to PSR-0 for folder structure/namespaces, but for classes?

It seems redundant as the language has literal keywords for this very purpose.

```php
abstract class AbstractFoo {}

interface InterfaceFoo {}

trait TraitFoo {}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There isn't a convention for this; especially in PHP. This can all be organized however you'd like.

With the additions of [**namespaces**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php) in PHP 5.3, I don't see the need to add `Abstract` or `Interface` prefixes/suffixes to the actual class names.

Just name things as they are!

Comment: worth pointing out that if you wanted to conform to the PSR by laws, it stipulates that you must include `Interface` as a suffice for interfaces. http://www.php-fig.org/bylaws/psr-naming-conventions/

Comment: @wired00 true, but I'm a bit confused by that, what exactly is a PSR "by law"? Is that part of one of the PSRs (PSR-2, PSR-4)? It is not enforced by PHP Code Sniffer when PSR-2 and PSR-4 are enforced by it.

Comment: @maček Personally, I feel it does add value to name these more than "as they are". I like seeing that it is an interface or an abstract class every time I see the type. Otherwise it is easy to get confused and forget how the hierarchy is setup between different inheritors and implementers and I end up having to look it up often, which is very distracting. Seeing right away that a class is abstract or an interface is a pretty good memory aid to where/how it fits in with other related classes and interfaces, which helps me be sure the wrong one was not chosen, or rather which one was chosen.

Comment: @still_dreaming_1 I mean literally there are PSR `by laws` :-) In this case there is a PSR Naming Convention By Law. It includes naming for abstract classes, interfaces and traits. https://www.php-fig.org/bylaws/psr-naming-conventions/ I added an answer for this as the accepted answer seems "wrong" or at least misleading and there was no direct mention of the PHP FIG recommendations

Comment: @still_dreaming_1, Bylaws are an organizing document that are sometimes legally required (such as for a non-profit in Illinois). Bylaws serve as a (usually high-level) guide to how an organization should operate. PHP-Fig's Bylaws are NOT standards on how other developers should operate - they're standards for how PHP Fig operates. So these naming conventions say "PHP-Fig folks will write our PSR code THIS way", is how I understand it.

Comment: The [extended coding standards PSR](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) does NOT detail naming convention for interfaces, though all of their examples use the FooInterface convention (as their bylaws require).

Answer (score 19):

The PHP-FIG project indeed suggests a naming convention via the PSR  Naming Convention "ByLaw" https://www.php-fig.org/bylaws/psr-naming-conventions/

It states:

- Interfaces MUST be suffixed by Interface: e.g. `Psr\Foo\BarInterface`
- Abstract classes MUST be prefixed by Abstract: e.g. `Psr\Foo\AbstractBar`
- Traits MUST be suffixed by Trait: e.g. `Psr\Foo\BarTrait`

These conventions are generally followed in  packages

Comment: I'm still confused about the difference between a PSR and a bylaw. Why don't they just make these conventions part of PSR-4?

Comment: Actually being part of PSR-2, or some more modern version of that, would make more sense than PSR-4 I think.

Comment: @skill_dreaming_1 yep I find that strange too. As per the Bylaw page "Our bylaws help us act consistently and in line with our agreed upon processes", this is a fair enough statement for licencing, voting policies etc but naming conventions seems it should be included in a PSR already. So yeah, I'm not sure on that

Comment: And to make things more confusing, the title of that page is PSR Naming Conventions, which implies it is part of a PSR even though it doesn't seem to be part of any particular one of them.

Comment: I voted negative, because it's not in the PSR-* sections, its about collaborating writing PSR with the team. It's 'their' rules to make clear code to understand the PSR itself, it doesn't mean that you must follow it in your code. So no, there isn't a name convention for Intefaces, Abstract, etc.

Comment: @Dazag That's correct PSR Naming Convention is just internal set of rules. But it looks quite reasonable and in my opinion can be use by regular developer!

Comment: in the psr-naming-conventions they also use`psr` as the name of the vendor folder. Why do they not call the vendor folder `vendor`? Not sure if this is the best source, because as pointet out, its used internally.

Comment: @KrzysztofSzala there is a difference between "it's specified in the PSR" to "I consider the PSR team a relevant set of people because of the way they program so I will copy what they do when there isn't a convetion to follow.". 
I don't disagree with that, since I follow PSR but I do follow other way of naming convention from people I consider more relevant than the guys in the PSR team when it comes to "unspecified rules". So this answer is not valid, since it doesn't answer the question properly.

Comment: @Dazag Yes, that's true, the answer could be a little bit misleading. Anyway, what kind of naming convention do you use usually?

Comment: I've followed the same approach as the PSR team for a long time, from a few months until this day, I'm improving by trying to make my code more human-understandable following this approach: https://blog.nikolaposa.in.rs/2019/01/06/better-naming-convention/

Answer (score 18):

Although there's not any convention, I think it is a good practice using `Abstract` prefix and `Interface` suffix for respective components. It helps to understand better the code at a glance, IMO.

Comment: It is part of "a convention", but it is not "the convention", since that doesn't exist. It is part of the PSR naming conventions from their "bylaws". Although I'm a bit confused as to the difference between a specific PSR (PSR-2, PSR-4) and a bylaw: https://www.php-fig.org/bylaws/psr-naming-conventions/

Answer (score 6):

Going against most of the other answers, I would suggest that it's better *not* to add a prefix or postfix to the class. The language has literal keywords such as `abstract, interface, class, final` for this purpose.

The following actually breaks clean code principals:

```
abstract class AbstractPerson 
{

   // ...
}
```

Similar thinking to "comments are generally bad, as it suggests the code is not easily readable". If your classes, inheritance and their contracts are engineered in a clear and readable fashion that makes sense, there is no need for prefixing.

**Behavioural design**

It's usually possible to name things in a manner that reflects their behaviour. For example in a logging subsystem:

```
interface Loggable
{
    public function getLog(): string;
}

trait WritesLogs
{
    public function writeLog(): void
    {
        file_put_contents("logs.txt", $this->getLog());
    }
}

abstract class Event implements Loggable
{
    use WritesLogs;

    public function asLog(): string
    {
        return "{$this->getName()} at {$this->created_at}";
    }

    abstract public function getName(): string;
}

class FooCreated extends Event
{
    public function getName(): string
    {
        return 'Foo was created';
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not easy to tell at a glance that `FooCreated` is extending an abstract class. Not a game changer, but I personally prefer it so I can easily identify them in a directory list.

Comment: This guy says it better than I can.   Re how to name classes
https://youtu.be/-J3wNP6u5YU?t=220

Comment: (paraphrasing) "if classes and contracts are clear/readable fashion there is no need for prefixing" - How do you know which is which when you have `UserAddress` DTO, and `UserAddress` interface, and `UserAddress` Service and... given they are related the may very well end up in the same place together, some class, factory, etc

Answer (score 5):

Naming your abstract classes and interface by using:

- Abstract*
- *Interface

Will keep your codebase clean, nice and obvious to your team what are the prototypes, what are the contracts and what are the concrete implementations.

Naming conventions are here to increase our productivity in any circumstance, so "name as you like" is far from good idea.

Even though FIG group does not propose naming convention for abstract classes and interfaces - if you examine major open source PHP projects, you will see that almost all of them uses this convention.

Comment: yes, there is a PSR by law https://www.php-fig.org/bylaws/psr-naming-conventions/

Comment: At the moment when this answer was given - there were no PSR naming conventions dealing with this topic. They were added later on.

Answer (score 2):

Conventions are what you see them like: the language itself doesn’t force any conventions other than those that makes the parser able to read your code. Basically, you should have conventions set up on your own for a particular project, or better, for all of your projects. However, working in teams of different people could lead to conventions not being followed, it really depends on the programmers.

From my experience, I would suggest following something like "design-by-contract". Name your contracts (interfaces) like you would name your implementation class, and then give your implementation a more specific name (or fallback to MyContractNameImpl, known mostly from Java I guess). Also, many modern IDEs know whether your class is an interface or abstract, so there is really no need to put that in it’s name. I also find contracts named like "IMyContract" not really good, for the same reasons.